# How to sort using Realm?

Tags: database, swift, sorting, realm

I don't know how to sort using Realm.  My current code is.

```
data = realm.objects(WorkoutSet)
data = data!.sorted("date")
```

I want to sort *date* an `Int` from high numbers to low numbers. The docs need more information and the GitHub link throws a `404` message.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with 'sort date and Int from 1 to 0'?

Comment: What does the exclamation point (`!`) do in `data!`?

Comment: @JoshPinter it means you are saying "I am 100% sure there is a valid value in `data`", so go ahead and unwrap it

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can add an `ascending` parameter to the `sorted` method:

```
data = data!.sorted("date", ascending: false)
```

This sorts your WorkoutSet using the date field in descending order.

**Update**

With Swift 3 and the latest RealmSwift version this has now changed to:

```
data = data!.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
```

If you want to evaluate the sort criteria yourself you could use:

```
data = data!.sorted(by: { (lhsData, rhsData) -> Bool in
   return lshData.something > rhsData.something
})
```

But be aware that sorting your results by yourself does return an `Array` instead of a Realm `Results` object. That means there will be a performance and memory overhead, because `Results` is lazy and if do the sorting with the above method you will lose that lazy behavior because Realm has to evaluate each object! You should stick to Results whenever possible. Only use the above method if there really is no other way to sort your items.

Comment: I think we need to wrap ascending: false in {}, as sorted("date", {ascending:false})

Comment: No, that's not correct. `ascending` is a simple boolean parameter. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: Ah yes, it is with Swift, as you clarified. With Realm Javascript, we need to use as I stated sorted("date", {ascending:false})

Answer (score -6):

Using Sort.ASCENDING or Sort.DESCENDING

```
import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.RealmModel;
import io.realm.annotations.Index;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass;
import io.realm.annotations.Required;

@RealmClass
public class Pojo implements RealmModel {
    @Index
    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    protected Long id;
    protected Date data_field;
    protected int int_field;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

import java.util.List;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmQuery;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import io.realm.Sort;

public class Dao {
    public List<Pojo> getAllById(Long id) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<Pojo> query = realm.where(Pojo.class);
        query.equalTo("pojo_id", id);

        RealmResults<Pojo> result = query.findAll();

        result = result.sort("data_field", Sort.ASCENDING);
        result = result.sort("int_field", Sort.DESCENDING);

        //detaching it from realm (optional)
        List<Pojo> copied = realm.copyFromRealm(result);

        realm.close();

        return copied;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question asks about Realm in Swift and not java.

Comment: Can we sort realm query result in respect to list(array) of objects as we can do it in Mongodb?