# Sorting a List in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a List of objects, which I need to sort by a `date` property. I'm using that list to display the items in a `UITableView`

My problem is that, sorting a List in **Realm** returns a `Results<myItem>` instead of a `List<myItem>` object.

What is the proper way to **sort a List in Realm** without converting it into a Results object?

Comment: What is the reason you require it to be a list?

Comment: The List has a to-many relationship to a parent object, so it is natural to leave it as a list

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, it would seem most logical to me to insert the objects in a sorted manner, instead of sorting them later on.

Comment: Thing is that the date can be later changed by the user, requiring a sort again

Comment: Well, in that case you could of course check what position the object should move to, and use the `move(from:to:)` function to change the order. I don't know how efficient this would be though.

Comment: Otherwise, I think using the built-in `sorted` function would be the way to go, especially since it would update automatically, even though you would prefer to not use that

Comment: @Gori sorting the list into a Results object is the workaround I ended up using. Unfortunately, it doesn’t persist the List in the correct order, but at least it lets me display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround can be:

1. add extra field like `timestamp` of your date property (in millis), everytime you insert a record. (not required if you are sorting data based on data field)
2. sort query `data = data!.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)` [for more options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296670/4647628)
3. Realm query will return RLMResult only.[for unmanaged object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39040081/4647628)